# You can’t change the startup disk to the selected disk?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup

I am booting my macbook through an external usb drive. At system preferences - startup disk when I try to select my internal harddisk it says:

```
You can’t change the startup disk to the selected disk. The bless tool was unable to set the current boot disk.
```

What could be the issue with the internal drive or how can I fix it?

Comment: This, combined with your earlier question, tells me the HD is dead or dying. Concentrate on recovery of any data not yet backed up & then get a new drive

Comment: Can you access the files on that internal HD when booting from the USB stick?

Comment: I can open it in the finder but won't let me reinstall/unmount it

Comment: Can you boot into safe mode? (CMD + R at startup)

Comment: No not possible

Comment: I'm not sure there's even a point in trying an SMC, so I'd concentrate on recovery as Tetsujin suggested earlier. You have plenty of reaons to do that by now.

Comment: This could be caused by the drive not having a GUID partition scheme.

Comment: MacOS does not recognise NTFS disks. If you put Windows 10 onto an external SSD like i have done ( and it works beautifully with TRIM on the thunderbolt connection) and not a bootcamp partition on the internal Mac disk then this is what you get. Mac cannot bless the external disk. I tried Paragon NTFS to read and write to the NTFS disk but you still cannot select the 'startup disk' in mac system preferences to set an external disk or use Paragon NTFS to auto reboot into windows. I'm using legacy boot on a MacBook Pro 2015, and have no EFI partition on the Windows disk.

Comment: It works absolutely fine otherwise. The answer, THEREFORE, is that there is no answer! Have trawled the internet to no avail. Just reboot the mac with the option key held down and select the Windows disk to boot from. Voila! Forget Startup disk.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd try is [resetting the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063):

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P,
   and R.  Turn on your Mac.
3. Press and hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys immediately after you
   hear the startup sound.
4. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup
   sound **for a second time**.
5. Release the keys.

...and see if that solves your problem. If it doesn't, I'd start worrying about a hardware fault.

Comment: it restarts but then in the startup apple logo screen there are some error messages: can't perform kext scan : no kext summary

Comment: Does this happen after you've heard the second chime and released the keys, or before?

Comment: After the second time

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I was adding a new external HD to boot from.  My original boot drive started giving me this error.  It was still usable, and I could boot from it if I held the option key down during startup and selected it, but could not select it from Sys Prefs without getting an error.  I tried all the Disk Utility things to no avail.  It was only when I reset the NVRAM with the cmd, option, p & r solution that everything went back to normal.